# Why is my react redux state not causing a re-render?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, state

Hello i've an issue where my redux state not causing a re-render when i'm trying to use a selector. I'm pretty new to react-redux and typescript. I've been trying to google this and most internet threads say it's because you need to create a new object and return that to let redux know that state has changed. Which im already doing.
But my object is not re-rendering, the state IS updated but not causing a rerender.

What am i doing wrong?

My Redux reducer

```
import { Computer, GraphicsCard } from "../../interfaces";

const initialState: Computer = {
    graphicsCard: null,
}


interface SelectGraphicsCardAction {
    type: "SELECT_GRAPHICSCARD";
    payload: GraphicsCard;
}

interface UnselectGraphicsCardAction {
    type: "UNSELECT_GRAPHICSCARD";
}


export type Action = SelectGraphicsCardAction | UnselectGraphicsCardAction

export const computerReducer = (state = initialState, action: Action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "SELECT_GRAPHICSCARD": {
            const { payload } = action;
            console.log(state, payload)

           const newState = {
                ...state,
                graphicsCard: {
                    ...state.graphicsCard,
                    ...payload
                }
            }
            //This evaluates to false
            console.log(state === newState)

            return newState
        }
        case "UNSELECT_GRAPHICSCARD": {
            return {
                ...state,
                graphicsCard: null
            }
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

My Redux Store

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { computerReducer } from './reducers/ComputerReducer'
// ...

 export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    computer: computerReducer
  },
})
```

Im selecting/using the state here.

```
function SelectedComputer() {
  const computer = useSelector((state: Computer) => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { graphicsCard } = computer;

  //Logging correct state
  console.log(computer)

  return (
    <div className="fixed top-10 right-4 bg-white rounded-t-lg">
      <p className="text-center font-bold border-b-1 border-b-black bg-gray-100 rounded-t-lg shadow-md">
        Selected Parts
      </p>
      <div className="flex flex-row">
        <CpuFill className="m-1" />
        {graphicsCard ? (
          //Not rendering this when updating state.
          <p>{graphicsCard.name}</p>
        ) : (
          <p>No Graphicscard selected!</p>
        )}
        <Trash className="flex justify-center"/>
      </div>
```

EDIT:
Here is a snippet where am using dispatch to update the state.

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { Button, Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Component, ComputerComponent } from "../interfaces";
import { Action } from "../redux/reducers/ComputerReducer";

interface ComponentCard {
  component: Component;
  buttonText: string;
  type: string;
}

interface DomainImage {
  [key: string]: string;
}

const ComponentCard: FC<ComponentCard> = ({ component, buttonText, type }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const imageMap: DomainImage = {
    "inet.se": "https://cdn.inet.se/gfx/ext/226/brand-assets/inet-logo2.jpg",
    "komplett.se":
      "https://cached-images.bonnier.news/gcs/di-bilder-prod/mly/fcb28d10-158c-485b-814c-b461baa0e188.jpeg",
    "webhallen.se":
      "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/6/65/Webhallen_2021.svg/revision/latest?cb=20220420201224",
  };

  return (
    <Card className="flex flex-row items-center w-50 shadow-md mt-2 mb-2">
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center mr-3">
        <img className="h-36 w-40 p-2" src={component.imgUrl} />
      </div>
      <div className="flex-1 text-left">
        <h4 className="text-base">{component.name}</h4>
        <p>
          <span>
            ArtNr: {component.articleNumber}, Manufacturer:{" "}
            {component.manufacturer}
          </span>
        </p>
        <h4 className="absolute right-36 top-10">
          <span>{component.price} :-</span>
        </h4>
      </div>
        <Button
          color=""
          className="absolute right-5 h-10 w-20"
          onClick={() => dispatch({ type, payload: component })}
        >
          {buttonText}
        </Button>
        <a href={component.url} target="_blank" className="absolute right-5 bottom-0">
          <img
            className="w-15 h-10"
            src={imageMap[component.domainName]}
            alt={component.name}
          />
        </a>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Comment: The code looks fine. Do you call the actions with `dispatch`?

Comment: Yes, i forgot to add that, will update with snippet where i use dispatch to update state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, you are using an extremely outdated (pre-2019) style of Redux here that will end up being about 4x the code you would write with modern Redux - especially in combination with TypeScript.

I would highly recommend you to follow the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) and the [TypeScript QuickStart](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript) that will show you all the additional types you have to set up (it's a lot less than what you have right now).

The source of your problem is likely an accidental state modification, which can also happen outside of reducers in legacy Redux - in modern Redux you would get an error immediately at the point where you make the mutation - saving you hours of debugging. So I'd really recommend you just switch over and you'll probably be rid of this bug.

Comment: Thanks, i will check that out! :) A more general redux question. 
My state has 6-7 child objects in my parent object. Is it better(best practice) to split them in to several reducers instead of having one big object? or does that not matter?

Comment: That really depends on how you feel comfortable with it. You should always select the exact data you want though and not the full state like in your example. So do `const graphicsCard = useAppSelector(state => state.graphicsCard );`

Comment: Alright, i'm actually gonna use all 7 of the state objects in that component that's why i'm using the whole state, but maybe its better to split it in to several selectors anyway since it may not need a rerender everytime the whole computer object updates? :)